# Do any software developers know what the General Systems Model or an Organizational Model is?

Tags: model, requirements

Apparently the General Systems Model and Organizational Model are part of requirements phase of a software development project using the waterfall model (according to my professor), but we did not learn about this in my software engineering course, neither of my two software engineering books mention them, and Google doesn't seem to know what they are either. I'm not a business developer and I don't have to do any of this stuff normally, so I am in unfamiliar territory. I have to have the requirements, analysis, and design phase of a software project finished by tomorrow (it was assigned yesterday) and I can't proceed on the requirements section because my professor is requesting these unusual things for it. I would ask my professor if I thought there was even a remote chance of getting a response, but that is unlikely.

Comment: Found something here: http://mumbai-university.education4india.com/327/structured-systems-analysis-and-design/ where it mentioned "general systems approach". Not sure if it is what your prof meant.

Comment: Tell your prof that StackOverflow thinks he's making this up - tell him we demand a citation for this. And, why's he teaching "waterfail" anyway?

Comment: @John I will tell her that you demand a citation for this, but truly I am wondering myself where she got these names from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organizational Model basically is something on top of which you shall lay your software on. OM is description of how one organization is *khm* organized - e.g. how is the hierarchy of employees structured - or what are the requirements of some job position to do it's job (data wise) ... You apply different models business logic on the basis of Organizational Model . Business Logic is probably more familiar term (hint: MVC).

Now, GSM is more abstract than that. 'cause systems are more abstract things than organizations - but its role in software development project is basically the same as OM, just on more abstract level.

All in all that is just another useless matter to learn that, if you are lucky, would be applied in background thinking about your software while the software is in preparation phase, in another words, never :)

Cheers